# C++ sum of odd digit

Tags: c++

I have created a program in which the function can add all the odd digits; however, I would like print out all the odd digits, for example, sum_odd_digits(2139) return 1+3+9 = 13 while sum_odd_digits(1024) return 1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum_odd_digits(unsigned int i){
      unsigned int a =0;
      while ((i !=0)&&(i%2 !=0)){
      a +=i%10;
      i/=10; 
} 
     cout << a;
}
int main(){
     sum_odd_digits(2139);
}
```

Anyone can give me some tips for printing out odd digits?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You should have division operations (/1000,/100,/10) to sort out the digits first, before testing them for odd or even.

Comment: Have you tested for instance `sum_odd_digits(9312)`?

Comment: Sorry, I only test for 2139; however, if I input 9312, the program does not work T^T

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
int sum_odd_digits(unsigned int i){
    unsigned int a = 0;
    while (i != 0){
        if ( i % 2 == 1 )
            cout << i % 10 << ' ';
        a += i % 10;
        i /= 10;            
    } 
    return a;
}
```

It looks through all digits, and if digit is odd it prints it. It return digits sum.

Comment: Ohh Thanks. It can print out all the odd digits.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The following example separates the digits of a number, and prints them if they are odd.

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int num,temp,factor=1;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  temp=num;
  while(temp){
      temp=temp/10;
      factor = factor*10;
  }

  printf("The odd digits of the number are: ");
  while(factor>1){
      factor = factor/10;
      switch (num/factor) {
         case 1:
         case 3:
         case 5:
         case 7:
         case 9:
            printf("%d ",num/factor);
            break;
      }
      num = num % factor;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohh thanks you give another idea for this question which is inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((i !=0)&&(i%2 !=0))
```

This will stop as soon as either condition is false; when `i` becomes zero, or when the value is even. However, you don't want to stop when you find the first even value, you want to continue testing digits and only stop when `i` becomes zero. So this should be structured as

```
while (i != 0) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        // final digit is odd
        a += i%10;
    }
    i/=10; 
}
```

You could compress the first an last lines into a `for` loop if you like

```
for (; i != 0; i /= 10)
```

Comment: you mean I should use for loop instead of while loop, right?

Comment: @Amy: Yes, use one or the other, according to taste.